# Error setting UITextView inputView in React Native iOS Native Component

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm attempting to use a react native library which seems to be unmaintained to display a custom keyboard when a text input is clicked.

The library works fine on Android but the iOS native code throws an error executing the function:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(install:(nonnull NSNumber *)reactTag withType:(nonnull NSString *)keyboardType)
{
  UIView* inputView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:((RCTCxxBridge *)_bridge).parentBridge moduleName:@"CustomKeyboard" initialProperties:
    @{
      @"tag": reactTag,
      @"type": keyboardType
    }
  ];

  UITextView *view = (UITextView*)[_bridge.uiManager viewForReactTag:reactTag];

  view.inputView = inputView;
  [view reloadInputViews];
}
```

Debugging shows that both inputView and view are initialised and not null

The iPhone simulator gives the error:

```
Exception '- [RCTSingleLineTextInputView setInputView:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance <instance id> was thrown while invoking install on target CustomKeyboard with params {1653, NumInput}
```

NumInput is the correct name for the keyboard I'm trying to install.

What is it about inputView that is causing an issue when trying to set it as the inputView for the UITextView?

My object c skills are poor so I apologise if the fix is obvious.

React Native version 0.57.2

Comment: did you get solution for the problem ?